# Black Screen after install kernel 4.2-rc3 on Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I hope you can help me, ever after compile and install the Kernel 4.2-rc3 or even the kernel 4.2-rc4 i get black screen on the primary display always, with the next steps you can reproduce this issue

1-Download the kernel from https://www.kernel.org/
2-Run make oldconfig to create .config file with your running kernel's configuration
3-and compile the kernel with the command : make -j8 deb-pkg
4-After that you get 4 .deb files that you can install in your machine with "sudo dpkg -i linux-....."

After follow this steps I reboot mi machine for apply the changes in the kernel and boot with the new kernel but always after this the black screen appears in the main display but in the second display like DP or HDMI I can see for example a tty.

I hope you can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar problem to what I've found

I ran 'apt-get dist-upgrade' on debian stretch, and then laptop display becomes black on boot up. This also happens with latest Arch boot usb.

I can get around this by either:

boot kernel 4.1 (as opposed to 4.2) from GRUB

run 'vbetool dpms on'

Hope this helps

Matt